# AngularFire2 - Filter list by array

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, angularfire2

I'm new to FireBase, and I'm trying to set up a simple database. Here's my data:

```
{
  "employees" : {
    "employee1" : {
      "name" : "Anthony"
    },
    "employee2" : {
      "name" : "John",
      "reviews" : {
        "review1" : true,
        "review2" : true,
        "review3" : true
      }
    }
  },
  "leaders" : {
    "leader1" : {
      "company" : "Strawberry",
      "name" : "Martin",
      "reviews" : {
        "review1" : true
      }
    },
    "leader2" : {
      "company" : "Blueberry",
      "name" : "Carlos",
      "reviews" : {
        "review2" : true,
        "review3" : true
      }
    },
    "leader3" : {
      "company" : "Greenberry",
      "name" : "Peter"
    }
  },
  "reviews" : {
    "review1" : {
      "comment" : "Test1",
      "date" : "Thu Jul 06 2017 14:00:51 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
      }, 
      "review2" : {
        "comment" : "Test2",
        "date" : "Thu Jul 06 2017 14:00:51 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
      }, 
      "review3" : {
        "comment" : "Test3",
        "date" : "Thu Jul 06 2017 14:00:51 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want the following functionalities:

1. Get reviews on an investor
2. Get reviews written by an employee

My questions are the following:

- Is my data structure correct, according to my functionality needs?
- What query should I use to do the functionalities? I've thought about first get the leader object, then get the reviews with some kind of filter based on leader reviews array.
- If it's possible to get the leader and the related reviews, all in one query, that would be great.

As an example let's say I want to get leader1's reviews.

```
 db.object('/leaders/leader1').subscribe(res => {
        this.leader = res;

//THIS IS THE PROBLEM: GET REVIEWS ON LEADER
        db.list('/reviews', {
          query: {
            equalTo: this.investor.reviews
          }
       }).subscribe(queriedList => {
           this.reviews = queriedList
       });
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: My piece of advice to you, "Is my data structure correct, according to my functionality needs?" this type of questions are off topic here on stackoverflow. Also what's your real problem here? Right now your question is too broad. 
"Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to respond, Fabio. I did not know that data structures were not allowed to be answered on Stack Overflow, so my apologies for that. Thank your for linking me up with the How to Ask page, however, if you remove the data structure question, there is only one question left - What query should I use to do the functionalities? Please let me know if there is anything specific you're missing to answer my question.

Comment: It's not about data structures, but about asking if "x is correct" or "I did Y, is this best way?"

Comment: Alright, Fabio. I've edited my post to be more specific now.